# Can multiple smartimage xtypes appear on one dialog tab in AEM?

Tags: aem

The out of the box (OOTB) page properties dialog in Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) (CQ5) provides an Image tab.  I would like to add a couple more images to the dialog, but I don't want to create a separate tab for each one.

For instance, is there a way to include an image on the "Advanced" tab within a dialogfielset?  I tried this, but it does not seem to render properly.

One thing I am considering is to extend the slideshow xtype and each image would be a separate "slide"

Are there better approaches?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's **possible** to have multiple `smartimage` xtypes on a tab!

Widgets API document for [smartimage](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.html5.form.SmartImage):

> Note that the component is mainly designed for use on a separate
>   dialog tab. You may use the component inside a
>   CQ.Ext.layout.FormLayout optionally if you provide a **suitable height
>   setting**.

Here are codes for dialog:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    height="{Long}600"
    title="dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <panel
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Panel with two Images">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <firstimage
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        cropParameter="./firstimage/imageCrop"
                        ddGroups="[media]"
                        fieldLabel="first image field"
                        fileNameParameter="./firstimage/fileName"
                        fileReferenceParameter="./firstimage/fileReference"
                        height="{Long}200"
                        name="./firstimage/file"
                        rotateParameter="./firstimage/imageRotate"
                        title="First Image"
                        width="{Long}200"
                        xtype="html5smartimage"/>
                    <secondimage
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        cropParameter="./secondimage/imageCrop"
                        ddGroups="[media]"
                        fieldLabel="second image field"
                        fileNameParameter="./secondimage/fileName"
                        fileReferenceParameter="./secondimage/fileReference"
                        height="{Long}200"
                        name="./secondimage/file"
                        rotateParameter="./secondimage/imageRotate"
                        title="secondimage"
                        width="{Long}200"
                        xtype="html5smartimage"/>
                </items>
            </panel>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

And the following is the result:
[image: dialog with two images in single tab]

Comment: Nice! I must have glanced right past that documentation. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to create this component. i have added this component but where to add image or we can provide path image. please help

Comment: Add your component to a page, and then choose some images from the dialog. The paths of images should be save under the content node of the page. And you can change the path there