# Image Gallery Component AEM

Tags: aem

I have a requirement to add multiple image (drag and drop) for a component.As of now am extending the image component.Is there any OOTB component available ? .Please provide me a solution to achieve the functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can multiple smartimage xtypes appear on one dialog tab in AEM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897531/can-multiple-smartimage-xtypes-appear-on-one-dialog-tab-in-aem)

Answer (score 0):

CQ provides a xtype "slideshow", it might help you.
OOTB component slideshow("/libs/foundation/components/slideshow") uses slideshow xtype.
It only allows you to add multiple images and customizations need to be done as per requirement.

AEM toollbox providing StructuredMultiList xtype which is extension of slideshow xtype.StructuredMultiList allows us to add more fields to our slides.
Below link can be used as reference.

URL : https://github.com/Velir/AEM-Toolbox/tree/master/source/ui/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/aemtoolbox/widgets/StructuredMultiList